# What are good values for u and d in Silva and Almeida's backpropagation algorithm?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

Silva and Almeida's algorithm improves on the existing backpropagation algorithm by introducing individual, adaptive learning-rates for each weight. The value for the new learning rate is computed as follows:

[image: Learning constant for the next step]

I read that the constants `u` and `d` are set to be `u > 1` and `d < 1`. Those constraints are rather broad, so are there any general guidelines for setting these values or do I have to figure it out by experimentation for my specific problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read that good "starting" values to fit most problems are to try  u = 1.2 and d = 0.8 but i can't find the source right now.

Edit:  [I found it, PDF page 10-11](http://www.lx.it.pt/~lbalmeida/papers/AlmeidaHNC.pdf)

Also note the comments about how to improve upon the algorithm by introducing a momentum term, if you don't have that already...

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect! Yes, I already implement momentum.